# Writing a script to find State associated with Zip codes

Tags: google-sheets

I'm doing a project for school with a lot of zip codes and I was wondering if it would be easy to write a script that would search https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ZIP_code_prefixes or a database like it for the zipcode in the cell next to it and return the state it's in.

Could someone walk me through it?

Comment: A better way for you to approach this within the spirit of StackOverflow would be to think your way through the high level behaviors, then break that down into digestible chunks. Tackle those pieces, and come back with questions about specific problems you aren't able to solve. The wiki source you linked to is useless as a searchable source; look for a web api or ingest the data yourself as @pnuts suggests.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree it is probably advisable to reproduce a static copy of the table in the spreadsheet, you could try something like:

`=VLOOKUP(--LEFT(H1,3),IMPORTHTML("https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ZIP_Code_prefixes","table",LEFT(H1)+1),2,0)`